# How do I use regex to match a substring before/after the colon?

Tags: r, split, stringr

I want to split `info` into `Refseq ID`, `cDNA level change` and `Protein level change`, where `Refseq ID` represents the substring from the start to the first colon `:`, `cDNA level change` is the substring between the first and second colon, and `Protein level change` is the substring after the second colon.

```
library(stringr)

df=read.csv("variant_calls.txt", sep="\t")
info=df["AAChange.refGene"]
id=stringr::str_extract(info, "SRR.(\\d{6})")
aa=info[!id]

> dput(info)
structure(list(AAChange.refGene = c("NM_002725:c.C301T:p.P101S", 
"NM_001024940:c.T1054A:p.Y352N", "NM_001098209:c.T109C:p.S37P", 
"NM_152539:c.G955A:p.E319K", "NM_032421:c.A2422G:p.T808A", "NM_003141:c.G431A:p.G144E", 
"NM_006645:c.C749T:p.S250L", "NM_206927:c.C778A:p.P260T", "NM_012240:c.G209A:p.G70E", 
"NM_152336:c.A382C:p.K128Q", "NM_002773:c.G750C:p.W250C", "NM_001797:c.C2125T:p.R709W", 
"NM_058216:c.C797A:p.A266D", "NM_198977:c.C1543T:p.R515W", "NM_000307:c.C356T:p.A119V"
)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected output:

| Refseq ID | cDNA level change | Protein level change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NM_001024940 | c.T1054A | p.Y352N |
| NM_001098209 | c.T109C | p.S37P |
| NM_152539 | c.G955A | p.E319K |
| NM_032421 | c.A2422G | p.T808A |

Comment: You can use `tidyr::separate` for this: `tidyr::separate(info, AAChange.refGene, c("id", "aa"), ":", extra="merge")`

Comment: @MrFlick, sorry I edited my question. The `aa` is the substring between the first and second colon

Comment: Then just use `tidyr::separate(info, AAChange.refGene, c("id", "aa"), ":", extra="drop")`

Comment: Are these in a text file to begin with? Why not just use `read.delim()` instead of `read.csv()`?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can try using `seperate()` instead of the regex.

```r
library(tidyr)

info %>% 
  separate(AAChange.refGene,
           c("Refseq ID", "cDNA level change", "Protein level change"),
           sep = ":", extra = "drop")
```

```r
      Refseq ID cDNA level change Protein level change
1     NM_002725           c.C301T              p.P101S
2  NM_001024940          c.T1054A              p.Y352N
3  NM_001098209           c.T109C               p.S37P
4     NM_152539           c.G955A              p.E319K
5     NM_032421          c.A2422G              p.T808A
6     NM_003141           c.G431A              p.G144E
7     NM_006645           c.C749T              p.S250L
8     NM_206927           c.C778A              p.P260T
9     NM_012240           c.G209A               p.G70E
10    NM_152336           c.A382C              p.K128Q
11    NM_002773           c.G750C              p.W250C
12    NM_001797          c.C2125T              p.R709W
13    NM_058216           c.C797A              p.A266D
14    NM_198977          c.C1543T              p.R515W
15    NM_000307           c.C356T              p.A119V
```

Comment: sorry I edited my question. The `aa` is the substring between the first and second colon

Comment: @melolili updated for your update. Study the code a bit and you'll see how all these tweaks you are making to the question are foundationally the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sub` for a base R option:

```r
df$id <- sub(".*?:([^:]+):.*", "\\1", df$AAChange.refGene)
df$aa <- sub(".*?:", "", df$AAChange.refGene)
```

Comment: sorry I edited my question. The `aa` is the substring between the first and second colon

Comment: @melolili Try the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite method for this kind of task is `extract`:

```
library(tidyr)
info %>%
  extract(AAChange.refGene,
          into = c("Refseq ID", "cDNA level change", "Protein level change"),
          regex = "(.*):(.*):(.*)")
      Refseq ID cDNA level change Protein level change
1     NM_002725           c.C301T              p.P101S
2  NM_001024940          c.T1054A              p.Y352N
3  NM_001098209           c.T109C               p.S37P
4     NM_152539           c.G955A              p.E319K
5     NM_032421          c.A2422G              p.T808A
6     NM_003141           c.G431A              p.G144E
7     NM_006645           c.C749T              p.S250L
8     NM_206927           c.C778A              p.P260T
9     NM_012240           c.G209A               p.G70E
10    NM_152336           c.A382C              p.K128Q
11    NM_002773           c.G750C              p.W250C
12    NM_001797          c.C2125T              p.R709W
13    NM_058216           c.C797A              p.A266D
14    NM_198977          c.C1543T              p.R515W
15    NM_000307           c.C356T              p.A119V
```

Comment: Curious to see what you make of my solution, which it seems is the only effective solution to your **updated** post.

Comment: This has errors. You only have 2 "into" groups while the regex will find 3. Also you magically made the column header names appear. That said, I was surprised to see this approach run slightly quicker than `separate()`.

Comment: Well, that error of mine - thanks for pointing it out - was related to you changing your question almost completely. The `into` line was the old one relating to your old question. Now I've edited the answer.

Comment: Hah, I appreciate and share the sentiment regarding the changes to the question. I am not the OP :), my edit merely changed the markdown formatting. Thought it was a good solution so I wanted to give you the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R` with `read.csv` after replacing the first `:` with `,`

```
read.csv(text = sub(":", ",", df$AAChange.refGene),
    header = FALSE, col.names = c("id", "aa"))
             id               aa
1     NM_002725  c.C301T:p.P101S
2  NM_001024940 c.T1054A:p.Y352N
3  NM_001098209   c.T109C:p.S37P
4     NM_152539  c.G955A:p.E319K
5     NM_032421 c.A2422G:p.T808A
6     NM_003141  c.G431A:p.G144E
7     NM_006645  c.C749T:p.S250L
8     NM_206927  c.C778A:p.P260T
9     NM_012240   c.G209A:p.G70E
10    NM_152336  c.A382C:p.K128Q
11    NM_002773  c.G750C:p.W250C
12    NM_001797 c.C2125T:p.R709W
13    NM_058216  c.C797A:p.A266D
14    NM_198977 c.C1543T:p.R515W
15    NM_000307  c.C356T:p.A119V
```

If we don't need the last part after the `:`

```
read.csv(text = trimws(df$AAChange.refGene, whitespace = ":[^:]+",
   which = "right"), header = FALSE, col.names = c("id", "aa"), sep = ":")
             id       aa
1     NM_002725  c.C301T
2  NM_001024940 c.T1054A
3  NM_001098209  c.T109C
4     NM_152539  c.G955A
5     NM_032421 c.A2422G
6     NM_003141  c.G431A
7     NM_006645  c.C749T
8     NM_206927  c.C778A
9     NM_012240  c.G209A
10    NM_152336  c.A382C
11    NM_002773  c.G750C
12    NM_001797 c.C2125T
13    NM_058216  c.C797A
14    NM_198977 c.C1543T
15    NM_000307  c.C356T
```

Comment: sorry I edited my question. The `aa` is the substring between the first and second colon

Comment: @melolili your expected output still shows 'aa' as earlier one

Comment: @melolili try the updated one

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, the `fread()` function from the data.table package is quite handy for cases like this one:

```
data.table::fread(text = info$AAChange.refGene, sep = ":", header = FALSE, 
                  col.names = c("Refseq ID", "cDNA level change", "Protein level change"))
```

> ```
>        Refseq ID cDNA level change Protein level change
>  1:    NM_002725           c.C301T              p.P101S
>  2: NM_001024940          c.T1054A              p.Y352N
>  3: NM_001098209           c.T109C               p.S37P
>  4:    NM_152539           c.G955A              p.E319K
>  5:    NM_032421          c.A2422G              p.T808A
>  6:    NM_003141           c.G431A              p.G144E
>  7:    NM_006645           c.C749T              p.S250L
>  8:    NM_206927           c.C778A              p.P260T
>  9:    NM_012240           c.G209A               p.G70E
> 10:    NM_152336           c.A382C              p.K128Q
> 11:    NM_002773           c.G750C              p.W250C
> 12:    NM_001797          c.C2125T              p.R709W
> 13:    NM_058216           c.C797A              p.A266D
> 14:    NM_198977          c.C1543T              p.R515W
> 15:    NM_000307           c.C356T              p.A119V
> ```